# SQL query to select from two tables and return if a value exists

Tags: mysql, sql

i have two tables:

```
callcosts
callcosts_custom
```

is there a way i can select from both tables and return the value of `cost` from callcosts_custom if the row exists and if it doesnt exist, return the column `price` from `callcosts`

with the following `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE callcosts_custom.parent = callcosts.sequence
```

basically, the `callcosts` table has all of the default data in and custom data can be added per customer.

the relationship is as follows:

```
call_costs.sequence = callcosts_custom.parent
```

so i want to check if a row exists in callcosts_custom for a specific `callcosts_custom.customer`. if it does, it will return `callcosts_custom.cost` and if it does not exist to return `callcosts_price`

**updated query:**

```
select b.cost
```

from call_costs_custom b
where a.sequence = b.parent AND b.customer_seq = '124'
union all
select a.retail
from call_costs a
where a.sequence = '4706' and
      not exists (select 1 from call_costs_custom b where b.parent = a.sequence);

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking to `LEFT OUTER JOIN` one table on another, then use a `CASE` in your `SELECT` to conditionally choose one column or another.

Comment: have a look at my update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes . . . this sounds like a prioritization query.  This typically looks like

```
select ccc.price
from callcosts_custom ccc
where ccc.?? = ??
union all
select cc.price
from callcosts ccc
where cc.?? = ?? and
      not exists (select 1 from callcosts_custom ccc where ccc.?? = cc.??);
```

It is unclear from your question what the columns are.

Comment: ok, i changed your query (check my question update) this is returning the correct data but its showing all rows for the selected customer_seq in call_costs_custom and then its also showing the row from call_costs

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by left joining the tables (under the assumption that every row must exist in `callcosts` and may or may not exist in `callcosts_custom`, but not the other way round) and using `coalesce`. You haven't given too much information about the tables, but I'm assuming there's some ID column to identify the rows:

```
SELECT    c.id, COALESCE(cc.price, c.price) AS price
FROM      callcosts c
LEFT JOIN callcosts_custom cc ON c.id = cc.id
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
SELECT IFNULL(cc.cost, c.price) cost
FROM      callcosts c
LEFT JOIN cc.parent = c.sequence
```

Comment: i just tried this query from yours: `SELECT IFNULL(cc.cost, c.retail) cost
FROM      call_costs c
LEFT JOIN call_costs_custom cc ON c.sequence = cc.parent WHERE c.sequence = '1536' and cc.customer_seq = '58'` but thats returning no rows. although the row with `sequence` `1536` exists in `call_costs`